# How to make a taxonomy vocabulary overview page with Drupal 7

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a simple vocabulary named **knowlegde** with several terms. This vocabulary is localized and can be used in many languages. My question now is how can i make a simple page where i can display all content tagged with that vocabulary. The important thing is that the (localized ) vocabulary is part of the url.

For example in german the url should look like

http://example.org/wissen

and in english it should look like

http://example.org/knowledge

Answer (score 1):

If you refered that taxonomy term in a content type then a listing page is created by default.

For example if you created a taxonomy named **Category**  and terms inside it are

1. Knowledge
2. courage

If you created a content type and refered category taxonomy then listing page will be at **category/knowledge** , **category/courage** and so on

**To display all the contents of the vocabulary** then

> Create a view of type Node
>
> Add a display of type block or page according to your need
>
> Add your desired fields(CCK) along with a field Taxonomy: Term
>
> Add a filter Taxonomy: Vocabulary and select is one of operator and choose the
>     particular vocabulary name.

This solution will include taxonomy terms associated with content node but filter according to the defined vocabulary in filter.

Comment: I know but i dont want to display a specific term like category/knowledge. I want to display a page who list all content with all terms of that vocabulary. The url should look like just /category and on that page i wannt all content with all terms from category :) Hope its clear

Comment: Then you need to create a view with that vocabulary as filter criteria...